# Powershell: How to check if group or account is deleted from SID?

Tags: windows, shell, powershell

I'm trying to export User right assignment with this command:
 `secedit /export /areas USER_RIGHTS /cfg d:\privs.txt` 
And then using Powershell I'm trying to translate SIDs to names. Here is my code:

```
$output=@()
$temp = "c:\"
$file = "$temp\privs.txt"
[string] $readableNames

$process = [diagnostics.process]::Start("secedit.exe", "/export /cfg $file /areas USER_RIGHTS")
$process.WaitForExit()
$in = get-content $file

foreach ($line in $in) {
    if ($line.StartsWith("Se")) {
    $privilege = $line.substring(0,$line.IndexOf("=") - 1)
    switch ($privilege){
    "SeCreateTokenPrivilege " {$privilege = "Create a token object"}
    "SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege" {$privilege = "Replace a process-level token"}
    "SeLockMemoryPrivilege" {$privilege = "Lock pages in memory"}
    "SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege" {$privilege = "Adjust memory quotas for a process"}
    "SeUnsolicitedInputPrivilege" {$privilege = "Load and unload device drivers"}
    "SeMachineAccountPrivilege" {$privilege = "Add workstations to domain"}
    "SeTcbPrivilege" {$privilege = "Act as part of the operating system"}
    "SeSecurityPrivilege" {$privilege = "Manage auditing and the security log"}
    "SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege" {$privilege = "Take ownership of files or other objects"}
    "SeLoadDriverPrivilege" {$privilege = "Load and unload device drivers"}
    "SeSystemProfilePrivilege" {$privilege = "Profile system performance"}
    "SeSystemtimePrivilege" {$privilege = "Change the system time"}
    "SeProfileSingleProcessPrivilege" {$privilege = "Profile single process"}
    "SeCreatePagefilePrivilege" {$privilege = "Create a pagefile"}
    "SeCreatePermanentPrivilege" {$privilege = "Create permanent shared objects"}
    "SeBackupPrivilege" {$privilege = "Back up files and directories"}
    "SeRestorePrivilege" {$privilege = "Restore files and directories"}
    "SeShutdownPrivilege" {$privilege = "Shut down the system"}
    "SeDebugPrivilege" {$privilege = "Debug programs"}
    "SeAuditPrivilege" {$privilege = "Generate security audit"}
    "SeSystemEnvironmentPrivilege" {$privilege = "Modify firmware environment values"}
    "SeChangeNotifyPrivilege" {$privilege = "Bypass traverse checking"}
    "SeRemoteShutdownPrivilege" {$privilege = "Force shutdown from a remote system"}
    "SeUndockPrivilege" {$privilege = "Remove computer from docking station"}
    "SeSyncAgentPrivilege" {$privilege = "Synchronize directory service data"}
    "SeEnableDelegationPrivilege" {$privilege = "Enable computer and user accounts to be trusted for delegation"}
    "SeManageVolumePrivilege" {$privilege = "Manage the files on a volume"}
    "SeImpersonatePrivilege" {$privilege = "Impersonate a client after authentication"}
    "SeCreateGlobalPrivilege" {$privilege = "Create global objects"}
    "SeTrustedCredManAccessPrivilege" {$privilege = "Access Credential Manager as a trusted caller"}
    "SeRelabelPrivilege" {$privilege = "Modify an object label"}
    "SeIncreaseWorkingSetPrivilege" {$privilege = "Increase a process working set"}
    "SeTimeZonePrivilege" {$privilege = "Change the time zone"}
    "SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege" {$privilege = "Create symbolic links"}
    "SeDenyInteractiveLogonRight" {$privilege = "Deny local logon"}
    "SeRemoteInteractiveLogonRight" {$privilege = "Allow logon through Terminal Services"}
    "SeServiceLogonRight" {$privilege = "Logon as a service"}
    "SeIncreaseBasePriorityPrivilege" {$privilege = "Increase scheduling priority"}
    "SeBatchLogonRight" {$privilege = "Log on as a batch job"}
    "SeInteractiveLogonRight" {$privilege = "Log on locally"}
    "SeDenyNetworkLogonRight" {$privilege = "Deny Access to this computer from the network"}
    "SeNetworkLogonRight" {$privilege = "Access this Computer from the Network"}
    "SeDenyBatchLogonRight" {$privilege = "Deny log on as a batch job"}
    "SeDenyServiceLogonRight" {$privilege = "Deny log on as a service"}
    "SeDenyRemoteInteractiveLogonRight" {$privilege = "Deny log on through Remote Desktop Services"}
 }
$sids = $line.substring($line.IndexOf("=") + 1,$line.Length - ($line.IndexOf("=") + 1))
$sids =  $sids.Trim() -split ","


$readableNames = ""
    foreach ($str in $sids){
            if($str.StartsWith("*"))
            {
                $str = $str.substring(1)
                $str
                $sid = new-object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($str)
                $readableName = $sid.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
                $readableNames = $readableNames + $readableName.Value + ", "
            }
            else
            {
            $readableNames = $readableNames + $str + ", "
            }
     }
    $output += New-Object PSObject -Property @{            
    privilege       = $privilege               
    readableNames   = $readableNames.substring(0,($readableNames.Length - 1))
    #else            = $line."property" 
    } 
 }
}

$output
```

So the Problem I have Is that I'm getting error
 `exception calling translate with 1 argument some or all identity referances could not be translated`

`$str` output shows me that when SIDs like 
`S-1-5-21-1042109134-4285797005-3901271436-1004` 
 `S-1-5-21-1042109134-4285797005-3901271436-1006` 
`S-1-5-21-1042109134-4285797005-3901271436-1007`
 are given to
 `$sid.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])`
function that causes errors. Thats because the corresponding group or account has been deleted. So is there any way to determine if the account or group is deleted from SID before calling `Translate` function. Thank you very much.

Comment: Use a `try { } catch { }` block.

Comment: Terminating and Non-Terminating errors.  You can set an ErrorActionPreference to silentlycontintue on Non-Terminating errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `try {} catch {}` to handle the exception from orphaned SIDs.

```
try {
    $readableName = $sid.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
} catch {
    Write-Host "Could not find SID"
}
```

Or wrap it as a function if you'd like:

```
function Test-SID ([string]$SID) {
    $SIDobj = new-object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($SID)

    try {
        [bool]$SIDobj.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])

    } catch {
        $false
    }
}
```